# How can I hear audio out of my headphones, but speak through my laptop microphone(since the headphone microphone doesn't work)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, audio, microphone, speakers

The problem I'm facing is that only my earphones work and so I can hear through them fine, but my headphone microphone is not working, and so I cannot be heared.

A temporary solution I thought of would be to have my laptop record my voice but have my earphones still output audio (so I won't have to make noise with the laptop audio).

The problem is when my headphones are connected (and therefore I can hear from the earphones), the computer will not record audio, but when they are disconnected (and therefore I can't hear from the earphones) it **will** record audio.

I've been trying to screw around with the windows settings to have this work with no success. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Most VOIP programs allow you to select what devices they use for audio input and output in their settings.

Comment: What program are you using to record audio?

Comment: Using discord, the only options I have for input are "default" and "microphone(Realtek High Definition Audio)". Changing these has no affect and work the same way i described above with disconnecting and connecting the headphones.